# Executing web-service calls in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, f#, task-parallel-library

I saw these questions [Recommendations for executing .NET HttpWebRequests in parallel in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976073/recommendations-for-executing-net-httpwebrequests-in-parallel-in-asp-net) and [Async.Parallel or Array.Parallel.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477931/async-parallel-or-array-parallel-map) from about a year ago and was wondering if the advice from them still stands or if there's now a better approach with [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

My case is closer to the second question, except I only need to hit 10(ish) different web-services instead of the same one 3000 times. As this is a web application, does that kind of request amplification change the suggested approach?  Is there a better approach to take?  How well can I expect something like this to scale as the number of users increases?

A few notes:

- Caching results will be the next implementation detail, but I would like to get the base functionality working first
- Each web-service returns very little data (under a kb), longest one takes no more than 3 seconds to return and I believe most of that is latency (generating results not computationally expensive)
- Calling web-services from the client won't work (I don't think) as some are in different domains
- Either C# of F# implementation would work as ideally this will be abstracted away to a method call that takes a `string` and returns a collection of `string`s

Comment: Regarding the cross-domain issue, we overcame this by using a service proxy in our web application.  It was very simple to implement.  Simply add a service to the project, have the service contract implement the remote contract(s).  Then implement the contract by simply passing arguments to the real service, and returning the results.

Comment: @Smudge202: Server proxy would solve the cross-domain issue but then as the number of users increasing I would basically be DDoSing my own servers =).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find this discussion relevant:[Async instead of Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310997/how-to-achieve-asynchrony-instead-of-parallelism-in-f)

Answer (score 3):

Web requests are not suitable for TPL, since they are IO, not processing. You already had all the necessary infrastructure in place since .Net 2.0: [`BeginGetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) and [`BeginGetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx). Keep a lid on the number of outstanding requests (~200 is a good consumer OS, ~2000 is for server flavours, after accordingly tweaking the TCP parameters, specially [`TcpNumConnections`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739819%28WS.10%29.aspx)) and make sure you adjust the [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx).

Trying to achieve high scale and high bandwidth/throughput by simply throwing synchronous IO calls on tens and hundreds of tasks via TPL will get you nowhere fast.

Comment: Damn, the free lunch remains elusive.