# How to send web requests parallely using C#.

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, httpwebrequest

I want to test my couple of webservices.
How to send httpWebRequests parallely?

Comment: The following question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747993/executing-web-service-calls-in-parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use the Task Parallel library. You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

For example you can call the Invoke method to perform a couple of delegates in parallel:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
   new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                        "http://www.google.com"
                    }
                    .AsParallel().ForAll(x =>
                                             {
                                                 var client = new WebClient();
                                                 client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(x));
                                                 client.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                                                     (o, e) =>
                                                         {
                                                             var result = e.Result; // html will be here
                                                             Console.WriteLine("Completed");
                                                         };
                                             });
```

Or this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(new List<string>
                                 {
                                     "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                                     "http://www.google.com"
                                 }, x =>
                                        {
                                            var client = new WebClient();
                                            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(x));
                                            client.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                                                (o, e) =>
                                                {
                                                    var result = e.Result; // html will be here
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
                                                };
                                        }
```

For more information read [Parallel Programming](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx)